# AppArmor genprof problem for apache2 on Ubuntu 18

Tags: apache2, apparmor, drupal

I am unable to create a proper AppArmor profile for apache2 on Ubuntu 18.

When I follow these steps, I am unable to scan and build a profile for apache2 because my website fails during the genprof procedure as follows:

Note: before I do anything I stop apache with "service apache2 stop"

1. I run aa-genprof apache2
2. I get the message to start my service and scan
3. I then "service apache2 start" in another terminal.
4. I then try to hit my drupal website and it fails with a "filelock" error.

The only way I can get my website back is to disable the profile as follows:

sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.apache2 /etc/apparmor.d/disable/

sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.apache2

I've removed the disable sym link and the apparmor apache2 config many times and tried to rerun aa-genprof many times but it fails every time.

I've also tried to put apache2 in aa-complain mode and tried aa-logprof too. I can't seem to get any apache apparmor logs to go to the syslog...

What do you recommend I do. I want to use aa-genprof to help me build an apparmor config for apache2.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to aa-genprof apache2. Apparmor profile is avalible as libapache2-mod-apparmor. Please follow the below github document.

[git hub document](https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/wikis/mod_apparmor_example)

1) You need apache2 profile libapache2-mod-apparmor.

```
apt install libapache2-mod-apparmor
```

2) Enable it

```
aa-enforce /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.apache2
```

If you are getting error like aa-enforce not found. int apparmor-utils

```
apt-get install apparmor-utils
```

3) To configure your appache, I followed the below:

```
a2enmod mpm_prefork
a2enmod apparmor
service apache2 restart
```

You can find my old answer in server fault:

https://serverfault.com/questions/932410/enabling-apparmor-for-apache2-in-ubuntu-18-04